# How to store a separate high score for each level

Tags: savegame, leaderboards, game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to make a game in game maker studio 2 where the highest score and ranking is saved for each level.

I have an idea on how to do this for an entire game, but not individual levels. How can I do this? (shown code takes control away from the character, moves them to the target room, and then compares score to high score)

```
if(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up))
 {
 with (Obj_player) { 
if (hascontrol) {
 hascontrol = false; 
SlideTransition(TRANS_MODE.GOTO,other.target); 
if(global.levelscore > global.levelhighscore)
{ global.levelhighscore = global.levelscore; } } } }
```

Comment: Use your method for the entire game but add another unique key to the save variable for each level.

Comment: Have you considered replacing your `global.levelhighscore` variable with an [array](https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Overview/Arrays.htm) containing an entry for each level in order?

Comment: No, that's a good idea

Comment: Thanks btw, forgot to say